# Is my tax return refund unsually late?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, income-tax-refund

Around May this year (2019) I submitted a (late!) tax return for the 2017 fiscal year. I did so by generating the form with some tool, and then mailing it to the IRS office that was specified online. I know the form arrived safely, since I can see this in the IRS website when I check for my tax return:

[image: Refund status screenshot]

However it's been over 5 months and this status has never changed. Is such a delay normal or should I pay for an international call to the IRS to ask them directly?

**Update**: I called and they said there had been some error in their processing (apparently not in my form), and now it's back on the pipeline. It can take up to 16 weeks since my call to be refunded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's not typical.

The [IRS refunds site](https://www.irs.gov/refunds) suggests you call if:

> - It has been 21 days or more since you e-filed
> - It has been 6 weeks or more since you mailed your return
> - "Where's My Refund" tells you to contact the IRS

It might take longer for prior year returns but I don't see any alternate timelines for prior year returns, in no case would I expect it to take 5 months to provide you a status update. If they do not have a proper mailing address it is possible you have missed correspondence.

I'm not familiar with international calling rates, but if it's prohibitive you can also correspond by mail. The following has international contact information:

https://www.irs.gov/help/contact-my-local-office-internationally

Comment: Thanks! It shouldn't be too expensive, I just had no clue if this was a usual timeframe or not for late returns.